# Call activity from fragment onkeydown event

Tags: android-activity, fragment, onkeydown

I have one MainActivity and different fragments,
In one of fragment have onKeyDown event,
How could I call MainActivity from Fragment,
and onKEyDown event in fragment can work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
@Override
public void onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // do stuff ...
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ParentActivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(myIntent); 
}
```